# Sorting posts by multiple values, combined

Tags: custom-field, meta-query, order, sort

[image: Sample Image for sorting reference]

In this image,

*1. The Black letters are default post titles*

*2. The number before the '**of**' is a custom field.*

*3. The number after the year is the post's published year*

Now I want to sort this according to title's alphabetical order. So it will be,
**C, D, D, L** in this case.

At the same time I want it to be sorted by yearly. So all the posts start in 'D' should be sorted by post year.

Also the number's that come before the '**of**' should be sorted in ascending order within that year.

The below code chunk didn't work

```
 $args = array(
         'posts_per_page' => 30,
         'category__in' => $idObj,
         'paged' => $paged,
         'meta_query' => array(
                         'relation'    => 'AND',
                         'custom_key' => array(
                                         'key' => 
                                         'original_act_ordinance_information_0_act_ordinance_number',
                                         'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                                         'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
                                          ),
                         ),
         'orderby' => array(
                      'title' => 'ASC',
                      'post_date' => 'DESC',
                      'custom_key' => 'ASC',
                      ),
         );
```

Where am I making the mistake?
and is there any solutions to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

[image: Alphabetically sorted]

So basically I want this...

So this image is sorted **alphabetically**, at the same time all the posts should be **sorted from latest year to the oldest**, meanwhile let's say there are multiple posts in the same year. IE: 16 of 2016, 23 of 2016 and 18 of 2016. I want them to be ordered in **ascending order**.

In conclusion, I want the posts to be ordered,

1. Alphabetically
2. (Within alphabetically ordered) Yearly
3. (Within yearly ordered) Numerically

At the same time.

In a peaceful world the sorted posts should look like this

[image: What exactly I wanted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely 100% on the order you are looking to achieve, but I think you need to spend a little more time with the documentation for `WP_Query`. An `orderby` array takes the name of a column in the `wp_posts` table OR `meta_value` or `meta_value_num` as the key, *not* the name of the custom field key (`custom_key` in your case). The actual name of the custom field is defined in the args array as `meta_key`.

If you look at the last two examples under [Orderby Parameters in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), you can see how this works and apply it to your situation. This is untested but gives you the general idea:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'category__in' => $idObj,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'original_act_ordinance_information_0_act_ordinance_number',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
         ),
     ),
     'orderby' => array(
         'title' => 'ASC',
         'post_date' => 'DESC',
         'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
     ),
     'meta_key' => 'original_act_ordinance_information_0_act_ordinance_number',
 );
```

You also had your `meta_query` set up incorrectly so I suggest you review that part of the `WP_Query` docs as well.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am gonna follow it up now. I will rephrase my answer as well, to be more clear what I needed. If things work out I will select your answer.

Comment: I have added some more information regarding what exactly I want, please have a look. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight have you tried the code I supplied? what is the result you are getting? I replaced `custom_key` with the name of what I assume is the meta key (the `original_act_ordinance_information_0_act_ordinance_number`, same as the `EXISTS` query) so try it now and let me know the result. On looks alone, it should be ordering like you desired. You may have to play around with SQL and work backwards... OR just use `$wpdb` and circumvent the `WP_Query` altogether

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay. Unfortunately I had give this project to another team member. And I thought I have marked yours as correct answer. Thank you for taking your time :)